# How to add SwiftUI custom ButtonStyle as a static extension

Tags: swift, swiftui

In swiftui3 you can use buttonstyle shortcut like so

```swift
Button("0") {print("pressed 0")}
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
```

I would like to do that with my custom buttonstyle class

```swift
struct CrazyButtonStyle:ButtonStyle{
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

calling it like this

```swift
Button("0") {print("pressed 0")}
    .buttonStyle(.crazy)
```

I have tried

```swift
extension ButtonStyle{
    static var crazy:CrazyButtonStyle {
        get {
            return CrazyButtonStyle()
        }
    }
}
```

but im getting this error

```
Contextual member reference to static property 'crazy' requires 'Self' constraint in the protocol extension
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Apple's suggested way:**

```swift
struct CrazyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}

extension ButtonStyle where Self == CrazyButtonStyle {
    static var crazy: Self { Self() }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
    Image(systemName: "forward.fill")
}
.buttonStyle(.crazy)
```

Source: [Develop Apps for iOS Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-card-view#Customize-the-Label-Style)

Answer (score 2):

```swift
extension ButtonStyle where Self == CrazyButtonStyle{
    static var crazy:CrazyButtonStyle {
        get {
            return CrazyButtonStyle()
        }
    }
}
```

adding where Self to the extension seems to work. But im not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score -2):

You can define something like the following:

```swift
struct CrazyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    HStack {
      Spacer()
      configuration.label.foregroundColor(.red)
      Spacer()
    }
    .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.90 : 1)
  }
}
```

Then, to apply it to a `Button`:

```swift
Button("Crazy Button") {}
  .buttonStyle(CrazyButtonStyle())
```

See [swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle) for reference.

Also [here](https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-button-style-animation/) are some other examples, with animations as well!

Comment: works but that is the old way (swiftui2 way) of doing it. I would like to know the new way (swiftui3) where you can do `.buttonStyle(.crazy)`